# Why am I getting error while using the Boost Library in C++?

Tags: c++

I am using the c++ boost library in one code to get large numbers in output.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout<<"Enter the value for a:";
    cin>>a;
    for(int x =1;x<=a;x++)
    {
        int128_t ans = pow(a,2*x)-pow(a,x)+1;
        cout<<ans<<endl ;
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But after running this, I am getting following error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:14:43: error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__promote_2<int, int, double, double>::__type' {aka 'double'} to non-scalar type 'boost::multiprecision::int128_t' {aka 'boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128, 128, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >'} requested
   14 |         int128_t ans = pow(a,2*x)-pow(a,x)+1;
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

What is the reason for such an error?

Comment: `int128_t n = 1.5` should already trigger this, you have a conversions between a float and an integer there.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What should I do then?

Comment: `std::pow()` with two integer parameters will give you a `double` value (verify that by checking cppreference.com though!). Start there, you need to find a replacement operation that does not convert to floats but uses e.g. Boost's `int128_t`internally and as returnvalue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I changed pow(a,2*x)-pow(a,x)+1; to int(pow(a,2*x))-int(pow(a,x))+1;     but still getting wrong output for a=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `ans` type is not `int128_t`.
After changing `ans` type to `auto` compilation works fine:

```
cat boost_error.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout<<"Enter the value for a:";
    cin>>a;
    for(int x =1;x<=a;x++)
    {
        auto ans = pow(a,2*x)-pow(a,x)+1;
        cout<<ans<<endl ;
        
    }
    return 0;
}

g++ boost_error.cpp
a.out
Enter the value for a:3
7
73
703

g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I am not getting correct output for a=10. What should I do?!

Comment: That approach keeps the double value which defeats the intended use of 128-bit integers.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt For a=3, I am getting intended output but for a=10, I shows garbage value. Why !?

Comment: Please take a step back and read [ask]. Point is, nobody here knows what *you* expect as output. Still, the usual approach is to find out whether `pow(a, 2*x)`, `pow(a, x)` or the combination of the three values is the problem. For that, start with a [mcve].